# What's wrong with this MySQL statement: DECLARE @ID INT

Tags: sql, t-sql, mysql

```
DECLARE @ID INT ;
```

This statement parses fine with MS SQL Server, but gives me

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @ID INT' at line 1*

Does anyone have any idea about the reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DECLARE is used in stored procedures/functions.

If you're looking to set a variable for just regular queries, use SET

Comment: -1 @ID Doesn't seem to work for me on MySQL 5.0 even inside procedures/functions.

Comment: -1 for answering the question? Works perfectly well as documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html

Comment: You only answered half of it.  When I try `DECLARE @ID INT ;` in a procedure I get: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@ID INT ;
END' at line 2".

Answer (score 3):

try naming the variable without the @

```
DECLARE id INT;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't use Declare in normal queries.

Try this:

```
SET @ID =(Select id from mytable)
```