# MySQL DECLARE Syntax (Converting from MSSQL)

Tags: mysql

MySQL Gurus,

I'm  converting some reports from a MSSQL database for usage on a MySQL Database, and don't seem to understand how the `DECLARE` works in MySQL.  Below is the SQL code for the report, as works in MSSQL.  I read that `DECLARE` can only be use in a nested function, I belive, but that just does not sound right to me.

Current Report SQL:  (I parse & replace the values of Current & Pending from my app code)

```
DECLARE @Current int;
DECLARE @Pending int;

SET @Current = [1];
SET @Pending = [3];

Select Ticket.TIcketID,
ISNULL((Select LocationName from Location where LocationID = Ticket.SiteCurrentLocation), 'Invalid Location') as [Current Location],
ISNULL((Select LocationName from Location where LocationID = Ticket.SitePendingLocation), 'Invalid Location') as [Pending Location]
from Ticket

where 
(SitePendingLocation > 0 AND SitePendingLocation <> SiteCurrentLocation) AND
(SiteCurrentLocation = @Current OR @Current = 0) AND
(SitePendingLocation = @Pending OR @Current = 0)
```

Any insight?

Thanks - Andrew

**EDIT**

Working, converted script - that it may help others:

```
SET @Current = '1';
SET @Pending = '1';

Select Ticket.TIcketID,
IFNULL((Select LocationName from Location where LocationID = Ticket.SiteCurrentLocation), 'Invalid Location') as `Current Location`,
IFNULL((Select LocationName from Location where LocationID = Ticket.SitePendingLocation), 'Invalid Location') as `Pending Location`
from Ticket

where 
(SitePendingLocation > 0 AND SitePendingLocation <> SiteCurrentLocation) AND
(SiteCurrentLocation = @Current OR @Current = 0) AND
(SitePendingLocation = @Pending OR @Current = 0)
```

Comment: You can either use SET by itself (no DECLARE) or replace @ with _ (or no prefix). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763718/whats-wrong-with-this-mysql-statement-declare-id-int for a similar question.

Comment: Thanks @dash - no need for the `DECLARE` at all then, great!  Now off to figure out what it does not like about `ISNULL`...

Comment: It's IFNULL ;-) - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: @dash, please 'answer' the question below with your first comment so I can accept it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use SET by itself (no DECLARE) or replace @ with _ or similar (or even no prefix).

I generally prefix mine with _

See [What's wrong with this MySQL statement: DECLARE @ID INT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763718/whats-wrong-with-this-mysql-statement-declare-id-int) for a similar question

As regards your other comment, it's IFNULL in MySql - See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

It's always the little things... :-)